# Japanese characters in R

Tags: r, unicode, character-encoding, character

I have a data frame in R, data one of the columns of this data frame is in Japanese characters.

When I try to update this data frame into SQL Server table using below statement

```
sqlSave(db,upld,tablename="SALES_DATA_TEST", append=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, colnames = FALSE)
```

I am seeing some unrecognized characters in place of my Japanese Characters.

How can I send these Japanese Characters into SQL Server Database?

Comment: Check the encoding of Japanese characters in R and in the SQL database to make sure they are the same. The programs must represent the characters in binary (i.e. a series of 0s and 1s) and sometimes programs use different encodings to represent the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Character set must match on both the SQL server and local environment R is running.

Make sure everything is in UTF-8 on both ends.
Otherwise Japanese text can be in any of legacy format (S-Jis, EUC...) a nightmare to handle. You don't wanna do it.